# Hide open directory

Tags: php, apache, file-io, directory

I have a website and right now users can just open a directory and see all files in it. How do I disable that?

I was thinking about the php.ini file, or generally any php configuration that might do the trick (it is an Apache server run with PHP).

Comment: No. `apache.conf` or `.htaccess`. PHP does not see your directory structure (until you call it to). Apache dispatches PHP if a `.php` file is requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable `Indexes` option in apache configuration.

Put this either in your `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess` in the root of the site.

```
Options -Indexes
```

This way, if the folder does not have an index page, the user will get a 403 Forbidden error.

Answer (score 1):

Put a text file named .htaccess to your root-dir of your website or the dir you want to hide with following content:

```
Options -Indexes
```